# Ajax insert from dialog box

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to insert a row into my repair_history table from a form inside a dialog box using ajax.

Here is the function that opens the dialog box with the form:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $( "#repair-dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function() {
                    insert(
                        $( "#repair-dialog-date" ).val(),                            
                        $( "#repair-dialog-id" ).val(),
                        $( "#repair-dialog-comment" ).val(),
                        $( "#repair-dialog-save_type" ).val()
                    );
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true);},500);
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
            }
        });

        $( "#record_repair" ).click(function() { $( "#repair-dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); });
    });     

    function insert(date,id,comment,save_type) {

        mydata = {
                "date"      : date ,                    
                "id"      : id    ,
                "comment"   : comment , 
                "camera_id" : "<?php= $products['camera_id']?>" };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "localhost/cibs/index.php/api/record_save/"+save_type,
            data:  {data:JSON.stringify(mydata)},
            dataType: "json",
            cache : false
        });            
    }
```

and here is the function inside the api.php controller that tries to insert:

```
function record_save()
    {            
        $this->load->database();        
        $mydata =   $this->input->post('data');         

        $date       = $mydata['date'];            
        $comment    = $mydata['comment']; 
        $id       = $mydata['id']; 
        $camera_id  = $mydata['camera_id'];     

    $table = "repair_history";            
        $data = array("camera_id" => $camera_id, "repair_id" => $id, "date" => $date, "comment" => $comment);       

    $this->db->insert($table,$data);    
    }
```

and heres the dialog box:

```
<div id="repair-dialog" title="Add New Repair" style="font-size: 15px;">
<form id="repair">
        <input style="height:0px; top:-1000px; position:absolute" type="text" value="">

        Repair id: <input type="text" id="repair-dialog-id" /><br>
        Repair date: <input type="text" id="repair-dialog-date" /><br>
        Comment: <input type="text" id="repair-dialog-comment" /><br>
        <input type="hidden" value="repair" id="repair-dialog-save_type">
</form>
</div>
```

Any replies really appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: what the problem is ? some errors ?

Comment: am not sure if it is relevant but if the issue is passing of data to server, then sometimes issue for me is solved by adding `contentType` option to the ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need stringify your object:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/cibs/index.php/api/record_save/"+save_type,
        data:  mydata,
        dataType: "json",
        cache : false
    });
```

And in php:

```
        function record_save()
        {            
            $this->load->database();   

            $table = "repair_history";            
            $data = array(
                "camera_id" => $this->input->post('camera_id'), 
                "repair_id" => $this->input->post('id'), 
                "date" => $this->input->post('date'), 
                "comment" => $this->input->post('comment')
            );       

            $this->db->insert($table,$data);    
        }
```

Comment: thought this could be it but still not working, thanks though

Comment: This actually turned out to be one of the problems with the code. Also, not putting http:// in front of the absolute url meant the controller wasn't being called!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your function `$this->input->post('data')` works, but you are posting the data as a json string, so you should make sure that you json_decode that data first.

Replace

```
$mydata =   $this->input->post('data');
```

By

```
$mydata =   json_decode($this->input->post('data'), true);
```